# Graph API (Http Status : 412 Precondition Failed - ErrorIrresolvableConflict)

Tags: azure-active-directory, microsoft-graph-api, microsoft-graph-calendar

I am using Microsoft Graph to create Calendar Events using Application Credentials where the organizer's email id will be used:

```
https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/<organizer_email_id>/calendar/events
```

Before the **Create Event**, I am issuing a `PATCH` to update the organizer's `displayName`, `givenName` and `surname`:

```
PATCH https://graph.microsoft.com/v1.0/users/{id}
```

I see the Event gets created, but it is sending the mail with old name and throwing the following error:

```
HTTP Status code : 412 Precondition Failed.

{
    "error": {
        "code": "ErrorIrresolvableConflict",
        "message": "The send or update operation could not be performed because the change key passed in the request does not match the current change key for the item.",
        "innerError": {
            "request-id": "a36e60a4-0a18-4574-9f7f-75f6c1cce8b4",
            "date": "2020-01-05T14:22:54"
        }
    }
}
```

It looks like the Event is reaching before the `patch` request is commited. I don't want to put any delay between two calls but the only option is before creating the event, fire a `get` request to confirm that name changed. Is there any other workaround or Microsoft needs to fix the bug if there is any?

Answer (score 2):

It seems to be an old known issue of Exchange.

Usually such issues need to be confirmed by Microsoft engineers.

I believe the most effective way now is to [contact the support team](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/azure-supportability/how-to-create-azure-support-request) and attach your request-id for investigation.